# VS Extension VSIX Save all unsaved documents

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, envdte

Is there a way to save all unsaved documents (files with the '*' in the VS editor tab) using DTE or something else in a VSIX command?

[image: unsaved file]

I'm creating a command that reads the current document's syntax tree, but I cannot access unsaved changes made to that document, so I wish to save all files open in the editor before running my code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.documents.saveall?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("File.SaveAll");
```

This will execute the Save All command, as if you executed it from GUI:

[image: 1]